# How to generate a "complex" url from a Mailer in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to generate an specific url in a mailer. Something like:

```
"http://localhost/teams/1/confirmation/123abc"
```

Where `1 = id of the team` and `123abc = confirmation token`.

And since the [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#generating-urls-in-action-mailer-views) tells me that I can't get URLs from context, neither from the Mailer nor the Mailer View, and I don't want to set the precise string in the mailer, I'd like to use it from variables, I've used the method [UrlFor](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/UrlFor.html#method-i-url_for), where I can get the route like this:

```
url_for(:host => default_url_options[:host],
               :port => default_url_options[:port],
               :controller => :teams,
               :action => :confirmation,
               :only_path => false,
               :team => team.id,
               :token => token.to_s)

# And it generates this: "http://localhost/teams/confirmation?team=1&token=123abc"
```

How do I use the method UrlFor to generate the link like I need to?

Comment: You will need to add the url_for method to a mailer helper.  Then you can just call it from your mailer

Comment: Isn't that a defined route? So you should be able to do something like `team_confirmation_url(1, 123abc)`